# using acs to authenticate wp7 app and a wcf service

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, oauth, azure, acs

I am scorching the web to find an example of how to use ACS with WP7 app and SOAP WCF service. All i can find are examples for REST WCF Data Services and not a simple WCF service.

Does anyone know an example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this: [Authenticating Users in a Windows Phone 7 App via Access Control Service, OData Services and Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/identitytrainingcourse_acsandwindowsphone7.aspx)

Hope this will help.